# what is the difference between grecaptcha.render vs grecaptcha.execute?

Tags: recaptcha

I can't understand the difference between grecaptcha.render vs grecaptcha.execute in invisible type recaptcha ? what is the difference between these two functions and when to use which one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- when you invoke execute() google decides if showing recaptcha
- when you invoke render() you are explicitly rendering the recaptcha